# Strange problem with custom cells and the uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, highlighting

I've got a navigation controller that has a grouped table with several rows, each using the same custom cell class.

If I select a row it navigates to the next view.

When I go back, just for a brief second, the background of the custom cell that was originally selected, expands to the full width of the screen then back again to the normal size.

I think it might have something to do with highlighting, but I can't tell.

Any ideas?

Howie